# How to handle the Map type in the reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Working on ng2 typescript project.
This was supposed to be straightforward. I need to put a `Map<string, Relationship>` in the store, but for some reason it didn't work:
I did the following to debug :

```
case relationActions.ActionTypes.SET_RELATIONSHIPS: {
  console.log('reducer');
  console.log(action.payload);
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    relationShips: action.payload
  });
}
```

The log shows the `Map` that i am expecting is there, But the redux dev tool shows :

```
relationShips(pin): null => {}
```

is it because `Object.assign()` can't handle `Map` ? 
What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript Map are mutable and you shouldn't use it as a state of a reducer.

If you really want to use a Map structure, you should take a look into [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) (--> [Map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map)).

If you don't want to use Immutable.js, you should have a state like that to simulate the content of a Map :

```
{
  [`yourId1`]: 'value 1',
  [`yourId2`]: 'value 2',
  // ...
}
```

and manipulate it with `Object.assign`.

Comment: should not or could not ? can `Object.assign` handle the `Map` ?

Comment: I don't think so. That's why Immutable js can become handy 